# Linq statement return answers for questions in each section

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

Using MVC 3 with EF 4.1.
I have a dynamic questionnaire that has sections which contain questions (user answer via textbox). When I am in edit form, I want to pull user answers with the questions. My query is below. My issue, I do I pull answers specific to userId? Ex: "Where Answers.userID=999"

```
**Answer Model:**
public int AnswerID { get; set; }
public int UserID { get; set; }
public int QuestionID { get; set; }
public string AnswerValue { get; set; }
public int ReviewID { get; set; }


var steps = from b in db.Section.Include(s => s.Questions.Select(q => q.Answers))
            orderby b.SectionOrder
            select b;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return a userID's answers to each question. Is this what you're looking for?

```
var steps = from b in db.Section.Include(s => s.Questions.Select(q => q.Answers.Where(a => a.userID == 999))
            orderby b.SectionOrder
            select b;
```

Comment: I received this error: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path